# Monitor a specific IoT device in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I have multiple devices in my IoT Hub and I want to set an alert when one specific device is not sending messages. I know you can set alerts when the IoT Hub in general is not getting any messages but I want to alert when a specific device isn't.

Example: Device1, Device2, Device3, Device4

Alert when Device1 is not sending messages.

I have tried searching all over and all that I found was a question from 2018 saying it was not possible (I am hoping this has changed).

Answer (score 1):

To your case specific I would leverage Device heartbeat pattern: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-identity-registry#device-heartbeat

> If your IoT solution needs to know if a device is connected, you can implement the heartbeat pattern. In the heartbeat pattern, the device sends device-to-cloud messages at least once every fixed amount of time (for example, at least once every hour). Therefore, even if a device does not have any data to send, it still sends an empty device-to-cloud message (usually with a property that identifies it as a heartbeat). On the service side, the solution maintains a map with the last heartbeat received for each device. If the solution does not receive a heartbeat message within the expected time from the device, it assumes that there is a problem with the device.